# MICROPYTHON/ESP8266 Как отправить данные на локальный хост через wi-fi?

Tags: python, micropython

У меня есть датчик dht11 и модуль esp8266. Мне нужно взять данные температуры и влажности и отправить на localhost. То есть я подключаюсь к wi-fi и отправляю с датчика запрос в локальный хост wi-fi, на путь `192.168.1.8/index.py?temperature=*температура*&wet=*влажность*`. Там у меня файл который добавляет данные в базу данных

У меня есть реализация на C++, но я хочу переписать на micropython. Но я ни где не могу найти информацию как сформировать код отправки данных на локальный wi-fi! Я долго искал и ничего не нашел. К сожалению и в официальной документации micropython не указано как отправить запрос.

Прошу дать место где я могу найти как сформировать запрос отправки на локаный хост сервера. Либо указать сам способ

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если коротко, то с помощью модуля `urequests` (это аналог модуля `requests` из "большого" Python)